# Dart: Get bytes from Flutter-Canvas without opening Flutter App

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, image-processing, flutter-canvas

**Background**

I am developing a pure Dart command line tool, which combines images from files.

Think creating NFTs by stacking images.

Using the pure Dart `image` library is slow, it takes about 11-20 seconds for one image sized 3000 x 3000.

**Tried**

Adding Flutter and using Flutter-Canvas to increase performance does not allow me to compile a Dart command line EXE.

I tried `flutter build windows` but the result always does open a window / head. And it does not work, just sits there.

**Questions regarding possible solutions**

1. Is there a way to combine images more efficently than [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image)?
2. Is there a way to create a Dart command line EXE which uses Flutter-Canvas as a library?
3. Flutter Tests run headless; is there a way to imitate that behaviour und thus run Flutter-Canvas headless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Flutter Tests**

One approach would be to hijack Flutter Tests, but these cannot be turned into a redistributable app or command:

https://andrewzuo.com/headless-flutter-apps-39168d20277b

https://andrewzuo.com/passing-arguments-to-headless-flutter-apps-773435c6eae6

**Command Line Package**

A different apporach would be to use this package, which modifies code in the `./windows` folder:

> This plugin allows you to run a flutter windows app in gui, or
> commandline mode. io.dart is used to access stdout and stderr

https://pub.dev/packages/commandline_or_gui_windows